# C++, reference parameter default value allowed in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

In .h file

```
class X{
private:
  std::chrono::minutes A;
public:
  X(std::chrono::minutes& a = std::chrono::minutes {5});
}
```

In .CPP file

```
X::X(std::chrono::minutes& a): A(a){}
```

Can std::chrono::minutes {5} go out of scope before getting assigned to A

for example,

```
void main()
{
   X x;
}
```

Is it guaranteed that object x will have member A with value std::chrono::minutes {5} always?

Comment: Did you even try to [compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2816f842f9701724) that code?

Comment: Have complied similar code and it works, I wanted to know whether it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: It probably works with a `const` reference member, and in that case it's guaranteed _"to work"_, yes.

Comment: surprisingly in ms c++ compiler it works without const reference as well.

Comment: Either you have an old MS compiler, or you don't use warning level 4  `/W4`.

Comment: @BoPersson /w4 is often useless.  I think more recent versions of the stl will compile silently with it, but many third-party libraries will generate such a blizzard of warnings that you essentially just ignore them all.  /w3 is often more productive.

Comment: @Ron : Not if you set `/permissive-`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Indeed. The `W4` level also issues a warning. `W3` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at a simplified version of your code:

```
#include <chrono>

struct X{
  std::chrono::minutes A;
  X(std::chrono::minutes const& a = std::chrono::minutes {5}) 
    : A(a){}
};

void main()
{
   X x; //Construction.
}
```

I have changed the reference to `const` in order to be standards compliant.

This code is fine.  The temporary is created in the context of main (at the line marked "construction"), and the reference parameter is bound to it.  The constructor is called, and once the parameter goes out of scope, the temporary is destroyed.

(Of course, if the member variable were a reference rather than an actual object, you would have a dangling reference.)

---

The compiler definition with a non-const reference is a constraint violation - you can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary.  Sadly, by default MSVC doesn't complain about this.  Until MSVC17, the only things you could do were:

- Promote warning C4239 to error with a suitable command line option or pragma
- Run with /w4. However at earlier versions this was essentially unusable because the STL was full of W4 warnings.  Third party libraries are quite likely to still be.
- Run with /Za (extensions disabled) - this often won't compile required headers.

*Finally* at VC2017, they have introduced [/permissive-](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/) (which I would strongly recommend as your default).

Comment: That's a nice answer, covering not only the standard, but also the specific example from OP and the solution for their compiler.